# Error 404 - Not Found while transforming XML to HTML in java

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jakarta-ee, xslt

I chose xml files in jsp page and then in post method of servlet i transform these files and display data on html page. but it does not work, when I choose an xml file, and validate I get the below error

```
"Error 404 - Not Found".
```

Below is the `java` code :

```
@WebServlet(name = "Validation", urlPatterns = { "/validation" })
public class Validation extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows-1252";
    static Document document;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
               try {
                   String xmlfile=request.getParameter("fichier");
                   String xsltfile="C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrateur\\Bureau\\test\\EDI3\\EDI";
                   File stylesheet = new File(xmlfile);
                   File datafile = new File(xsltfile);

                   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                   document = builder.parse(datafile);

                   // Use a Transformer for output
                   TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                   StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
                   Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

                   DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                   StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                   transformer.transform(source, result);
               } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
                   // Error generated by the parser
                   System.out.println("\n** Transformer Factory error");
                   System.out.println("   " + tce.getMessage());

                   // Use the contained exception, if any
                   Throwable x = tce;

                   if (tce.getException() != null) {
                       x = tce.getException();
                   }

                   x.printStackTrace();
               } catch (TransformerException te) {
                   // Error generated by the parser
                   System.out.println("\n** Transformation error");
                   System.out.println("   " + te.getMessage());

                   // Use the contained exception, if any
                   Throwable x = te;

                   if (te.getException() != null) {
                       x = te.getException();
                   }

                   x.printStackTrace();
               } catch (SAXException sxe) {
                   // Error generated by this application
                   // (or a parser-initialization error)
                   Exception x = sxe;

                   if (sxe.getException() != null) {
                       x = sxe.getException();
                   }

                   x.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                   // Parser with specified options can't be built
                   pce.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException ioe) {
                   // I/O error
                   ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
    }
}
```

Any guidance or tutorial that can make me understand where i am going wrong much appreciated.

Comment: I don't develop servlets but I would expect that the output is written somehow to a stream attached to that `HttpServletResponse response` you have and not to `System.out`. So try `StreamResult result = new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream());`. And usually XSLT works on XML with namespaces so you might want to use a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory. On the other hand the implementors of XSLT processors usually say that their native tree model is better than the W3C DOM so instead of using a DOMSource consider using a SAXSource or StreamSource.

Answer (score 0):

```
               response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
               StreamResult result = new StreamResult(response.getWriter());
               transformer.transform(source, result);
```

The content type already sets the encoding. The response can either write binary data with `getOutputStream()` or text as above, being encoded.